# Getting String Value Associated with Max Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I already have a query that uses a group by to get other values. For the second and last timestamp (which might be the same thing) I need to get the associated text value.

So what I want is (using a mix of SQL and English):

```
SELECT
      InitialTime,
      WHEN EventTime is 2nd one in group, get EventType as 2ndType,
      WHEN EventTime is last one in group, get EventType as MaxType
FROM
      MyTable
GROUP BY
      InitialTime
```

Some Data:

```
 InitialTime            EventType       EventTime
    6/9/2014 3:00:14       VoiceMail       6/9/2014 3:01:22
    6/9?2014 3:00:14       Disconnect      6/9/2014 3:02:13
    6/9/2014 3:00:14       Success         6/9/2014 3:05:15
    6/9/2014 3:15:15       Voicemail       6/9/2014 3:16:02
    6/9/2014 3:15:15       Hangup          6/9/2014 3:17:03
    6/9/2014 3:15:15       Fail            6/9/2014 3:19:00
```

My Query Above Should Get

```
6/9/2014 3:00:14         Disconnect    Success
6/9/2014 3:15:15         Hangup        Fail
```

So if I already have a grouping what is the best way to do this? Can't use a PARTITION query with a group by. The actual query groups on more fields actually, and brings back more results. Just keeping it simple for the question.

Comment: Looks like rank() might do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `row_number()` for this along with conditional aggregation:

```
select InitialTime, 
       max(case when seqnum_forward = 1 then EventType end),
       max(case when seqnum_backward = 1 then EventType end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by InitialTime order by EventTime desc) as seqnum_backward,
             row_number() over (partition by InitialTime order by EventTime asc) as seqnum_forward
      from table t
     ) t
group by InitialTime;
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response. Actually that "seqnum=1" will give an error, removing it seems o.k. Also just to be correct about the question, seqnum_forward = 2 in the select. Thanks again.

Comment: The `where` clause was wrong; it was in an earlier incarnation of the query and I didn't remove it.